# django relationship query

Tags: sql, django

I am struggling trying to learn a Django query against two models:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    dateCreated =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    jobName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    jobAddress = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I am trying to replicate the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoice, contact
WHERE invoice.contact_id = contact.id
AND invoice.id = 5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please go through the tutorial. This is an extremely simple query - For starters, you would do a `.get(id=5)`

Comment: I did try the tutorial, but it has eluded me. I have tried
data = Invoice.objects.get(pk=id)
but i just do not understand how to relate the contact field to obtain the contact information as well (address, etc)

Comment: You would do invoice.contact to access foreign key. The dot signifies accessing the foreign key field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically what you want is all information for the invoice and associated contact for the invoice having the id 5; to do this:

```
# Fetch the invoice with id = 5
invoice = Invoice.objects.get(id=5)
```

Now, to fetch information about the related contact, simply "follow" the foreign key:

```
print(invoice.contact.first_name)
print(invoice.contact.last_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the tip I needed. Works perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

you would rather set your models in this way: (Contact first, then invoice..)

```
class Contact(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Invoice(models.Model):
  contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="contact_invoice")
  dateCreated =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  jobName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  jobAddress = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

then this query:

```
contact = Contact.objects.get(id=someid)#just to get first contact object

contact_address = contact.address
contact_firstname = contact.first_name
contact_lastname = contact.last_name
invoice_of_this_contact = contact.contact_invoice.get(id=5)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Contact.invoice_set.filter(id=5)
```